# How to request an access token from OAuth using System.Net.Http? 401 Error

Tags: c#, rest, http, oauth-2.0, sharepoint-online

### Context

I am developing a simple application that requires to receive List Data from a company Online SharePoint site. In order to make REST requests, I must first retrieve an access token from Microsoft's access control service. Despite attempting some tutorials and reading documentation, I am new to REST/HTTP am am failing to do so.

### What have I tried?

- Used SharePoint appregnew.aspx to register my app, and generate "Client ID" and "Client Secret" values. https://[sitename].sharepoint.com/_layouts/15/appregnew.aspx
- Used Sharepoint appinv.aspx to authorize my app with read control and generate a "Tenant ID".
  https://[sitename].sharepoint.com/_layouts/15/appinv.aspx

```xml
<AppPermissionRequests AllowAppOnlyPolicy="true">
    <AppPermissionRequest Scope="http://sharepoint/content/sitecollection/web" Right="Read"/>
</AppPermissionRequests>
```

- Used SharePoint AppPrincipals.aspx to verify Tenant ID. https://[sitename].sharepoint.com/_layouts/15/AppPrincipals.aspx
- Attempted several methods of formatting the request with the following being the latest:

**Updated**

```cs
// Variables removed for security
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {               
        WebRequest myWebRequest;
        string stGetAccessTokenUrl = "https://accounts.accesscontrol.windows.net/{0}/tokens/OAuth/2";

        string tenantID         = "myTenantID";
        string resourceID       = "00000003-0000-0ff1-ce00-000000000000";
        string stClientID       = "myClientID";
        string stClientSecret   = "myClientSecret";
        string stSiteDomain     = "[myCompany].sharepoint.com";

        // URL Format
        stGetAccessTokenUrl = string.Format(stGetAccessTokenUrl, tenantID);
        myWebRequest = WebRequest.Create(stGetAccessTokenUrl);
        myWebRequest.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
        myWebRequest.Method = "POST";

        // Add the below body attributes to the request
        var postData = "grant_type=client_credentials";
        postData += "&client_id=" + stClientID + "@" + tenantID;
        postData += "&client_secret=" + stClientSecret;
        postData += "&resource=" + resourceID + "/" + stSiteDomain + "@" + tenantID;
        var data = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(postData);

        using (var stream = myWebRequest.GetRequestStream())
        {
            stream.Write(data, 0, data.Length);
        }
            
        var response = (HttpWebResponse)myWebRequest.GetResponse();
    }
}
```

### What doesn't work?

I receive a 401 Unauthorized error despite the app having been assigned permissions.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apologies, I forgot to return to this question upon resolving the issue. Credit to "Michael Han" within the comments of his own answer.

## Answer

By default, the SharePoint app-only permissions is disabled for the tenant. A tenant administrator must first run the following cmdlet in [PowerShell](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/sharepoint/):

```
Set-SPOTenant -DisableCustomAppAuthentication $false
```

This parameter supersedes all other privilege settings and must first be configured.

Answer (score -1):

You could refer to this article to get the access token :  https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/51982.sharepoint-read-online-list-data-from-c-console-application-using-access-token.aspx

```
 #region Get Access Token using TenantID and App secret ID & Password
 // URL Format
 //https://accounts.accesscontrol.windows.net/tenant_ID/tokens/OAuth/2 Jump
 
 stGetAccessTokenUrl = string.Format(stGetAccessTokenUrl, tenantID);
 myWebRequest = WebRequest.Create(stGetAccessTokenUrl);
 myWebRequest.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
 myWebRequest.Method = "POST";
  
   
 // Add the below body attributes to the request
 /*
  *  grant_type  client_credentials  client_credentials
  client_id  ClientID@TenantID 
  client_secret  ClientSecret 
  resource  resource/SiteDomain@TenantID  resourceid/abc.sharepoint.com@tenantID
  */
  
 
 var postData = "grant_type=client_credentials";
 postData += "&client_id=" + stClientID +"@" +tenantID;
 postData += "&client_secret=" + stClientSecret;
 postData += "&resource=" + resourceID + "/" + stSiteDomain + "@" + tenantID;
 var data = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(postData);
 
 using (var stream = myWebRequest.GetRequestStream())
 {
  stream.Write(data, 0, data.Length);
 }
 var response = (HttpWebResponse)myWebRequest.GetResponse();
 
 var responseString = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream()).ReadToEnd();
 
 string[] stArrResponse = responseString.Split(',');
  
 //get the access token and expiry time ,etc
  
 foreach(var stValues in stArrResponse)
 {
   
  if(stValues.StartsWith("\"access_token\":"))
  {
  //Console.WriteLine(" Result => " + stValues);
  accessToken = stValues.Substring(16);
  //Console.WriteLine(" Result => " + accessToken);
  accessToken = accessToken.Substring(0,accessToken.Length-2);
  // Console.WriteLine(" Result => " + accessToken);
  }
 }
```

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/28610035)

Comment: Thanks for the mentioning, I have added it.

Comment: Thanks for your input. I work through this article again from scratch and have updated my post to include an extraction of the code. I do however still receive an error.

Comment: It could be that the SharePoint app-only permissions is disabled for you tenant. Please run the below cmdlet to enable it:  Set-SPOTenant -DisableCustomAppAuthentication $false

Comment: This looks very likely to be the issue! Thank you. I’ll need to address it with my tenant administrator and come back to you.

Comment: @MichaelHan Sorry, I never did close this issue off. You were right indeed! I've posted the answer myself, however should you wish to do so yourself I will remove my own and accredit yours. Thank you.